# Found a mistake in a published paper at IEEE Transactions on Industrial Informatics

Tags: publications, research-process, errors-erratum

I discussed with my supervisors and all of them agreed that there is undoubtedly a mistake in part of the measurements of a recently published paper. The idea and the novelty of this paper is correct. However, part of the measurements is incorrect. A figure and a part of the comparison table should be modified.

The authors tried to compare the new technique with the old one. The false measured results are shifted up with the same amount of increase (new and old) so this mistake will not affect on the final conclusion. Actually, the mistake does not affect the abstract or the conclusion of the paper.

I think IEEE transactions do not accept corrections, right? So, this is the reason why authors can not correct it. Should I communicate with the editor or authors, or just ignore it?

Comment: All papers have errors.   Unless the authors have a personal web page where they post corrected version of their papers, then it's a waste of time.    Move on.

Comment: Is the paper also available on arXiv or some similar site?

Comment: Unfortunatelly Not

Comment: According to most of the suggestions, I think the best thing I just ignore it and move on.

Answer (score 38):

Don't overcomplicate this. Just send a friendly e-mail to the author(s) pointing out a possible (typographical) error.

Comment: It might even be an opportunity to open a collaborative relationship.

Comment: And then, what should authors do after receiving my email?

Comment: @John, whatever they wish to do: maybe nothing, maybe thank you for reading their paper so thoroughly, maybe go into further discussion with you...

Comment: Some researchers post errata on their professional websites.

Comment: @john At least not repeat the mistake and no longer use the flawed figure.

Comment: Understood. Then what should I do if I want to compare these false measured results in the comparison table.

Comment: @John That really was something you should have included in the question.

Comment: According to most of the suggestions, I think the best thing I just ignore it and move on. Thanks.